# In DQN how does the Q network not converge to the incorrect target?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-learning, deep-rl, dqn, deep-neural-networks

Whenever you are doing reinforcement learning you periodically update the target network based on the weights of the Q network. While I do understand this helps create a stable target I do not understand how it helps the Q networks accuracy. If I am updating the Q network much more frequently than I am the target network then wont the Q network converge to and estimate of the target network that is inaccurate since the target network is being updated much slower ?

Comment: I think this https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/13459/69468 already answers your question

Comment: oh wow perfect this is exactly what I needed